# onReceive() function of BroadcastReceiver always called when device is rebooted

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My program is implement BroadcastReceiver to setting Alarm. But I got issue : After setting time to alarm, I power off device. After that, I start device and onReceive() function of BroadcastReceiver always call. This is my code :

```
    <receiver android:name="com.futaba.broadcastservice.AlarmBroadCastReceiver"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You explicitly trigger that event for your receiver. If you don't want it to be triggered just remove the `intent-filter`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, If I remove BOOT_COMPLETED, alarm will cleared after reboot devices :(

Comment: Then I think the problem is bigger than this. Unfortunately, we can't help if you don't describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: You need two separate Receivers, or two separate actions, at least: One to handle the Alarm, and one to set it upon booting.

Comment: Dear Andrew, I wrote a program to setting Alarm. I used BroadcastReceiver and want to my alarm running after power off device. But when I power off my device, after that I start this,  onReceive() function always call.

Comment: @ChelseaDrogba That's the way to achieve what you want. After stating your device again you need to reschedule your Alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation of [BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)? It will run when the system is done booting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, If I remove BOOT_COMPLETED, alarm will cleared after reboot devices. Have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Possibly utitlize [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) perhaps? You could store your alarm(s) and retrieve them as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do to reschedule your alarm after rebooting.

Code goes on your receiver.

```
public class AlarmBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


Context ct;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
ct=context;
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
 {
  Intent contentIntent = new Intent(ct, AlarmBroadCastReceiver.class); 
  PendingIntent theappIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ct, 0,contentIntent, 0); 
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(year, month, day, hour,minute); 
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ct.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), theappIntent); 
 }
}
```

Just to be sure, you have to declare the `uses-permission` as follow

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver android:name="com.futaba.broadcastservice.AlarmBroadCastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Dear 113408, intent always return null :(